# How can I use continue statement in .ForEach() method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, anonymous-methods

Is there an equivalent to the continue statement in ForEach method?

```
List<string> lst = GetIdList();
lst.ForEach(id =>
{
     try
     {
       var article = GetArticle(id);
       if (article.author.contains("Twain"))
       {
         //want to jump out of the foreach now
         //continue; **************this is what i want to do*******

       }

       //other code follows
   }
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks for all the great answers. And thank you for the clarification that .foreach is not an extension method. I use this structure to keep the coding style consistent (a different programmer worked on another similar method in the same class)...and thanks for the links to why to avoid using .foreach.

Comment: if you want to use foraech so bad, use regular foreach instead

Comment: At the risk of overemphasizing, *please* please please please **please** use a standard foreach loop.

Comment: Recheck the term "continue".  Inside a loop, 'continue' means "stop processing this item and go to the next".  The keyword to exit processing completely is "break"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Personally, I would just use a standard foreach loop instead of `List<T>.ForEach`.

In this case, you can invert the condition (to avoid the code in that case) or call `return`, since your goal is to use a `continue` statement.  However, if you wanted to `break`, this would not work.  That being said, there are quite a [few other reasons to avoid `List<T>.ForEach`](https://ericlippert.com/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/), so I would consider switching this to a normal foreach statement.

Answer (score 85):

A) ForEach is not LINQ, it is a method on `List<T>`.
B) Just use foreach.
C) `return` will do it.

**Edit**

Just to clarify, what you are doing is providing a method that will be called for each entry in the list.  `return` will just apply to the method for that member.  The rest of the members in the list will still call the method.

Answer (score 13):

Just invert your `if` condition:

```
lst.ForEach(id => {
                      var article = GetArticle(id);
                      if (!article.author.contains("Twain"))
                      {
                          // other code here
                      }
                  });
```

Answer (score 4):

The method you're using is [`List<T>.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), a method defined on the class and not a LINQ extension method. This question actually has nothing to do with LINQ.

`return;` in the delegate passed to `List<T>.ForEach` should approximate using `continue;` in an actual `foreach` construct.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question:

```
List<string> lst = GetIdList();
lst.ForEach(id =>
{
    try
    {
        var article = GetArticle(id);
        if (article.author.contains("Twain"))
            goto _continue;
    }

    //other code follows

    _continue:;
}
```

The other answers are right, avoid `.ForEach()`.
`goto` should be avoided as well, although it's sometimes useful for shortcutting code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Continue in a foreach will loop back up to the top of the loop to the next item in the sequence. If that's what you want, return should do it. If you want to exit entirely, you may want to rewrite it using an actual LINQ method like Any().